# PHP read content from file error

Tags: php, file, directory, fgets

So i need to first open a directory, which I did and it works, after I need to make the files called "." and ".." to not be displayed, which I did and it works as well but after all of this I need to open every file from that directory (except for that "." and "..") and display it's content.

My code is here:

```
<?php
    $handle = opendir('data');
    $files = array();
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
        if ($file!=="." && $file!=="..") {
            $files = $file;
            print_r ('<p>' . ucfirst($files) .'</p>');
        }
        foreach($files as $dataz) {
            $handle2 = fopen('data/'.$dataz, 'r');
            while (!feof($handle2)) {
                $name = fgets($handle2);
                echo '<p>' . $name .'</p>';
            }
            fclose($handle2);
        }

    }
    closedir($handle);
?>
```

The error that i get is:
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/something/something/websitephp/weather.php on line 30 Call Stack: 0.0025 325952 1. {main}() /home/something/something/websitephp/weather.php:0

I think the error will be $dataz but i need that in order to indicate to the fopen what files should open.

Answer (score 1):

here

```
$files = $file;
```

you're over writing the array every time

use

```
$files[] = $file;
```

instead

**Edit**

```
$handle = opendir('data');
$files = array();
while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
    if ($file !== "." && $file !== "..") {
        $files[] = $file;
        print_r('<p>' . ucfirst($files) . '</p>');
    }
}

foreach ($files as $dataz) {
    $handle2 = fopen('data/' . $dataz, 'r');
    while (!feof($handle2)) {
        $name = fgets($handle2);
        echo '<p>' . $name . '</p>';
    }
    fclose($handle2);
}
closedir($handle);
```

Comment: That is very good, as it allows me to display the content from the files but now the name of the files are no more "Temperature" or "weather" but "Array". Any idea why? Thank you!

Comment: I did got that solved as well but I still have a problem. The first file is read and displayed correctly, but when it displays the second one it first displays again the content from 1st file and after the content from the 2nd file. The same goes for the 3rd file, first displays the content of first 2 files and after the content of the 3rd file.

Comment: [fgets](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php) gets a line of date from the file, not its name, if you want a list of filenames use [glob](http://uk1.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php)

Comment: oh yeah i see the problem you need to move the foreach loop outside of the first while loop, place it afterward

Comment: if i do this, it first displays the name of the files, all 3 of them, and then the content of all of them. To show you an example of how i want to look, that will be NameOfFile and on the next lines the content of the NameOfFile, after this NameOfFile2 and on the next lines the content of NameOfFiles2 and so on.. Sorry for not being very specific.

Answer (score 0):

I reorganized the code and made it work

```
$directoryPath = 'data';

// Get the file listing
$files = array();
foreach (scandir($directoryPath) as $file) {
    if (is_file("$directoryPath/$file")) {
        $files[] = $file;            
    }
}

// Display each files content
foreach($files as $file) {
    echo '<p>' . ucfirst($file) .'</p>';

    $contents = file_get_contents("$directoryPath/$file");

    // Print each line of the file
    foreach (explode("\n", $contents) as $line) {
        echo '<p>' . $line .'</p>';            
    }
}
```

Comment: this is good, but now each file will be in a `<p></p>` tag I think he wanted each line

Comment: @andrew Aah you are right, missed the fgets in the original code

Answer (score -1):

So, the solution that I have at the moment is:

```
<?php
    $handle = opendir('data');
    $files = array();
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
        if ($file!=="." && $file!=="..") {
            $files[] = $file;
            print_r ('<p>' . strtoupper($file) .'</p>');
        }
        foreach($files as $dataz) {
            $handle1 = fopen('data/'.$dataz, 'r');
            while (!feof($handle1)) {
                $name = fgets($handle1);
                echo '<p>' . $name .'</p>';
            }
            fclose($handle1);
        }
    }
    closedir($handle);
?>
```

It get's the files name except for "." and ".." and in reads the content of the files but when it displays the content of the second file first displays the content of the 1st file and after it displays the content of the second file, that is should display. For some reason $name seems to keep the content of the previous file in it.

to undestand what I am saying please have a look at the this [link](http://titan.dcs.bbk.ac.uk/~otoma01/p1/websitephp/weather.php).

Comment: Update your original post instead